# sufficiently different "that" they have

Tags: comparative-constructions

> Although functions in JavaScript are a kind of object, the typeof operator considers functions to be sufficiently different **that** *they have their own return value*.

I don't understand in what aspect the clause following **that** relates to the rest of the sentence. But, if I change **that** to **in that**, the sentence actually makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sufficiently ADJ that* here works in the same way as *so ADJ that* or *sufficiently ... [for SUBJ] to* in order to what degree of 'difference' functions exhibit.

> Functions are **sufficiently** different (from objects) **that** they have ... =
>   Functions are **so** different (from objects) **that** they have ... =
>   Functions are **sufficiently** different (from objects) **to** have ... =

If you say that they are *sufficiently different in that* you are saying something quite different: that functions are different enough to satisfy some need (which, presumably, has already been described). The *in that* clause describes some qualification or alternative description of that sufficiency; in this case it would a description of how they are sufficient, to wit, by having their own return values. In paraphrase:

> Functions are different enough (from objects) to meet our need, because they have their own values.